# Controller action parameter that implements an ICollection interface

Tags: c#, controller, icollection

So I'm trying to call a controller action like this:

```
Public Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] container)
{...}
```

```
public record container {
  public collection<Product> collection;
}
```

```
public record collection(ICollection<T> data) : ICollection<T> where T : Product
{
   ...ICollection implementation methods here
}
```

The problem is that once the collection inherits ICollection the controller cannot parse the request. But once the collection record looks like :

```
public record collection(ICollection<T> data) where T : Product
```

Then parsing works.

Is there a way to tell the parser to use the record constructor instead of the default way it works?

Comment: "once the collection inherits ICollection the controller cannot parse the request" What error do you get?

Comment: 400. "Bad Request"